# javascript variable in quoted php code in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

the title sounds weird, but here's  my question.
I am making this loop in Javascript that needs to call PHP variables.

```
    var data = new Array("<?php echo count($result) ?>");
    for (var i=0; i < "<?php echo count($result) ?>"; i++) {
        data[i] = "<?php echo $result[i] ?>";
    }
```

The third line is the problem.
I tried

```
            data[i] = "<?php echo $result [" + i + " ] ?>";
```

but it didn't work.

Any clever tip to solve this??

Comment: Are you really trying to call PHP code from JavaScript? Or these snippets of code come from a server side html+javascript generated by PHP?

Comment: @Nicolás this code is from a PHP file, and I need the javascript for d3.js.

Answer (score 3):

```
var data = <?= json_encode($result); ?>;
```

Comment: +1; This is really the most elegant (and secure!) way to do it.

Comment: oh it did not show up when I used jQuery.html(), but now I checked it works! Thanks a lot!!